# Apache Solr heatmap : How to convert in usable coordinate int2d array returned by heatmap

Tags: reactjs, solr, esri

I'm using faceting heatmap on a spatial field which then returns a 2d array like this
 "counts_ints2D",
                [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    [
                        0,
                        8,
                        4,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
    ...

I want to locate those cluster on the map but the problem is that I don't know how to convert that 2d array in geo coordinates.

There's absolutely no documentation out there showing what to do with those integer.
Can somebody give some guidance ?

Comment: That isn't the only part of the JSON structure returned? Usually you'll have columns/(min|max)(X|Y)/etc. which allows you to determine the size, in coordinates, of each bucket.

Comment: this is what the json is composed of
"facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {},
        "facet_ranges": {},
        "facet_intervals": {},
   "facet_heatmaps": {
            "lat_lon": [
                "gridLevel", 2,
                "columns", 32,
                "rows", 32,
                "minX", -180,
                "maxX", 180,
                "minY",-90,
                "maxY", 90,
                "counts_ints2D", [null,null,null, null,[0,8,4,0, 0, 0,0, 0,0,0,0,...],

Comment: That still does not say how I can transform the counts into something I can use to plot the clusters on the map ?

Comment: If you have minX, maxX and know that there are 32 columns, each column is `(maxX - minX) / columns` degrees wide. In this case, your buckets are 360 / 32 = 11.25 degrees wide, and 180/32 = 5.625 degrees tall. To find the lower left coordinates for each bucket, you can do `minX + (x * bucket_width)`, `maxY - (y * (bucket_height + 1))` (since Solr gives buckets starting from the left top and downwards, we use `maxY` and `minX`). This assumes you don't cross the date line (which would require a `% ..` as well.

Comment: @MatsLindh 
So basically I need to write a quick algorithm with 2 loops going over the array and for each count, I need to calculate the x,y coordinates
Let's take a quick example with the following "TResult":
[null,
[0,0,0,0,12,...],
...]
row 1: has null, we do nothing
row 2: [0,0,0,0,12,...]
Let's calculate coordinates for: 
row:2, column:5 then TResult[1][4]=12:
X= -180 + (5 *11.25) 
Y= 90 - (2*(5.625+1) ) 
Correct ?
Why do we have to subtract minX to the result of X and add maxY to calculate Y ?

Comment: Because one has the positive value at the top (where Solr's value is 0 - maxX is the first row of the array), while the other has the negative value at the left - where Solr's value is 0 - minY is the first column of the array.

Comment: Is my reasoning correct beside that ?

Comment: That sounds plausible, but I haven't drawn it out - Try it and see if your grid covers the whole globe.

Comment: the number of rows and columns is based on the grid level which also impact the clustering. Calculation is "almost" correct when grid level = 3 but really bad when grid level < 3. Can't we get correct coordinates for lower zoom level ?

Comment: When you decrease the grid level, you're not changing the zoom level - you're (simplified) changing how exact your counts will be (i.e. how much of the original coordinate should be considered for placing the point in a bucket). Unless you have a good reason to change it, you should probably let Solr calculate it for you.

Comment: Ok but what parmerer should be updatee in solr when i change zoom level in the UI ? The documentation says:The output shows the gridLevel which is interesting since it’s often computed from other parameters. If an interface being developed allows an explicit resolution increase/decrease feature then subsequent requests can specify the gridLevel explicitly.

Comment: When you change the zoomlevel, you'd change the X/Y-coordinates of the bounding box?

Comment: Yes i did change geometry as well. When using lower grid level there is minimum amount of cluster but displayed incorrectly, if i use bigger one like gridLevel=3 there's then way too many clusters that overlap.

Comment: There's something i did not mention which is that i use web mercator projection so after the calculation long, lat coordinates ffol 2d array, i convert them into meters before displaying them on the map. That shoukd not impact the result right ?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the clusters can overlap when you're getting counts that are for a certain range, and each range maps within a grid space given by squares/rectangles. Are you sure your conversions are correct? I'll have to play around with some test data to do anything further.

Comment: I guess then my conversion of the 2d array into degrees is wrong.

Comment: I'll provide you an the 2d array of the cluster of 1 traveller to locate on the map

Comment: You said that if i cross the date line, calculation would require %. Could you please elaborate on this ? (My map can be moved across 180 so date line can be crossed.)

Comment: Please find my query:
"facet.heatmap":"lat_lon",
"facet.heatmap.geom":"[\"-179.99999999999696 -52.531917327232904\" TO \"179.99999999999696 74.3804408931961\"]",
"facet.heatmap.distErrPct":"0.1" 
Result:
"gridLevel",3,
"columns",256,"rows",91,
"minX",-180.0,"maxX",180.0,
"minY",-53.4375,"maxY",74.53125,
Test done with one traveller, cluster is found at:

row=x=13
col=y=124
So,
var bucketX = minX + 124 * 1.40625 = -5.625
var bucketY = maxY - 13 * (1.40625 + 1) = 43.25
expected lat_lon:"55.8719,-4.43306"
my cluster is located in spain instead of glasgow. Please help!

Comment: I got rid of "+1" in the calculation bucketY. 
var bucketY = maxY - 13 * (1.40625 ) = 56.25
I'm almost there but it's still not at the right location...

Answer (score 0):

Going with the data you gave for Glasgow, and using the formula given in the comments, lets explore the coordinates in a python repl:

```
# setup
>>> minX = -180
>>> maxX = 180
>>> minY = -53.4375
>>> maxY = 74.53125
>>> columns = 256
>>> rows = 91

# calculate widths 
>>> bucket_width = (maxX - minX) / columns
>>> bucket_width
1.40625
>>> bucket_height = (maxY - minY) / rows
>>> bucket_height
1.40625

# calculate area for bucket in heatmap facet for x = 124, y = 13
# point in lower left coordinate
>>> lower_left = {
...     'lat': maxY - (13 + 1) * bucket_height,
...     'lon': minX + 124 * bucket_width,
... }
>>> lower_left
{'lat': 54.84375, 'lon': -5.625}

# point in upper right
>>> upper_right = {
...     'lat': maxY - (13 + 1) * bucket_height + bucket_height,
...     'lon': minX + 124 * bucket_width + bucket_width,
... }
>>> upper_right
{'lat': 56.25, 'lon': -4.21875}
```

Let's graph [these points on a map](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/untitled-map_212571), courtesy of open street map. We generate a small CSV snippet we can import on umap (select the up arrow, choose 'csv' as the type and enter content into the text box). To our coordinates to show:

```
>>> bbox = [
...   "lat,lon,description",
...   str(lower_left['lat']) + "," + str(lower_left['lon']) + ",ll",
...   str(upper_right['lat']) + "," + str(lower_left['lon']) + ",ul",
...   str(upper_right['lat']) + "," + str(upper_right['lon']) + ",uu",
...   str(lower_left['lat']) + "," + str(upper_right['lon']) + ",lu",
... ]

>>> print("\n".join(bbox))
lat,lon,description
54.84375,-5.625,ll
56.25,-5.625,ul
56.25,-4.21875,uu
54.84375,-4.21875,lu
```

After pasting these points into the import box creating the layer, we get this map:

[image: Points shown on Open Street Map / Umap]

Map based on Open Street Map data through uMap. This area encloses Glasgow as you expected.

Comment: Looks good thanks. But How do i plot my cluster as accurately as possible from the coordinates of that bounding box. Do I choose the middle of it ?

Comment: The middle of the area or the middle of the cluster? Because for the latter case you'll have to consider each coordinate, and you're not looking for heatmaps. Heatmaps divide the map into separate buckets and put each value inside those buckets, clustering groups nodes that are close to each other where there is a certain distance to other nodes. For the latter case I'm fond of leaflets PruneCluster.

Comment: If I wanted to use PruneCluster to plot my cluster up there, located in Glasgow, on a map , what would I pass as coordinates ?
I guess it's going to expect coordinates and the count for each group. right ?
So I need to send (x,y, count=1)
In my case I know the area but not the precise location, so I'm not sure of what coordinates I should send ?

Comment: To use prunecluster you'll have to fetch the coordinates of all the items in your active map view - PruneCluster will cluster and group them for you. It's (very) fast, but it'll as always depend on your requirements. PruneCluster will then group and count items within each cluster and recalculate as it or you find necessary. Be aware that this is something completely different than what you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that takes 180th meridian (date line) wrapping into account:

```
$columns = $heatmap['columns'];
$rows = $heatmap['rows'];
$minX = $heatmap['minX'];
$maxX = $heatmap['maxX'];
$minY = $heatmap['minY'];
$maxY = $heatmap['maxY'];
$counts = $heatmap['counts_ints2D'];

// If our min longitude is greater than max longitude, we're crossing
// the 180th meridian (date line).
$crosses_meridian = $minX > $maxX;

// Bucket width needs to be calculated differently when crossing the
// meridian since it wraps.
$bucket_width = $crosses_meridian
    ? $bucket_width = (360 - abs($maxX - $minX)) / $columns
    : $bucket_width = ($maxX - $minX) / $columns;

$bucket_height = ($maxY - $minY) / $rows;

$points = [];

foreach ($counts as $rowIndex => $row) {
    if (!$row) continue;

    foreach ($row as $columnIndex => $column) {
        if (!$column) continue;

        $point = []
        $point['count'] = $column;

        // Put the count in the middle of the bucket (adding a half height and width).
        $point['lat'] = $maxY - (($rowIndex + 1) * $bucket_height) + ($bucket_height / 2);
        $point['lng'] = $minX + ($columnIndex * $bucket_width) + ($bucket_width / 2);

        // We crossed the meridian, so wrap back around to negative.
        if ($point['lng'] > 180) {
            $point['lng'] = -1 * (180 - ($point['lng'] % 180));
        }

        $points[] = $point;
    }
}
```